# Treeview.FindNode Not working for me on 2 levels deep

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, treeview

I have a treeview which has a database structure as such:

```
Id  Unit                        ParentOrganizationalUnitId  Level
1   City wide                   NULL                          0
219 Finance Division            218                           1
4   City Hall Client Services   3                             2
```

This is is not all the data this is just three levels showing for reference purposes.

```
For Each row In SearchTag
                Dim parentNode As New TreeNode
                If row.Level = 0 Then
                    parentNode.Text = row.SearchTag.ToString
                    parentNode.Value = row.Id.ToString
                    trvSearchTag.Nodes.Add(parentNode)
                ElseIf row.Level = 1 Then
                    Dim childNode As New TreeNode
                    Dim parentchildNode As New TreeNode
                    childNode.Text = row.SearchTag.ToString
                    childNode.Value = row.Id.ToString
                    parentchildNode = trvSearchTag.FindNode(row.ParentSearchTagID)
                    If Not parentchildNode Is Nothing Then
                        parentchildNode.ChildNodes.Add(childNode)
                    End If
                ElseIf row.Level = 2 Then
                    Dim childNode1 As New TreeNode
                    Dim parentchildNode1 As New TreeNode
                    childNode1.Text = row.SearchTag.ToString
                    childNode1.Value = row.Id.ToString
                    parentchildNode1 = trvSearchTag.FindNode(row.ParentSearchTagID)
                    If Not parentchildNode1 Is Nothing Then
                        parentchildNode1.ChildNodes.Add(childNode1)
                    End If
                End If
            Next
```

I have this code ^^^^ which populates the treeview accordingly. the issue is my findnode function only worked on level 0 and level 1 when it goes to find level 2 options it returns nothing? Why is it doing that?

Side notes. 
Structure cannot change due to business req
Code can change.
I checked to make sure when it goes looking for a node with a parent id of say 3 that 3 actually did exist in the treeview prior to the search as its added on level 1 accordingly. via debugging the code and also via running the SPROC to see the results exist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that you're using the WebForms `TreeView` control:

The `FindNode` method takes a path to a node, not just the value of the node, as a parameter.

So, assuming your tree looks something like this:

```
 City wide                   
    Finance Division            
      City Hall Client Services
```

... and that each node has the appropriate ID as its Value property, code to find `City Hall Client Services` would look something like this:

```
 orgTreeView.FindNode("1/219/4")
```

Just this:

```
 orgTreeView.FindNode("4")
```

... won't work, because `4` is not a top-level node.

Comment: so I tried your theory out. It doesn't work? When I use the findnode function it does not permit / or even having it in a string like you have it up there. It only accepts decimals?

Comment: Maybe you're using a different TreeView control than I assumed you were. Are you using ASP.NET?  Something else?

Comment: I am using vb.net 4.0

Comment: But are you creating a Windows Forms app, a web app, or a WPF app?

Comment: @ace.nasir  It worked?  Great!  If my answer helped you, please consider marking it as your accepted answer.  Thank you.